# Get Item in Sitecore MVC by its path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, rendering

I have created a Web rendering and try to get a specific Item by its path.

Something like this :

Item item=Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");

Is it possible to get item using @Model.Sitecore() ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to just get an item in MVC rendering or do you want to get the current item/datasource?

Comment: I'm trying to get specific item. I tried to get item using query item=@sitecoe.context.item.selectitems(/sitecoe/content/home/global/*), but item is allways empty.

Comment: Ok, my answer below will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend it, but you can just get it in your view with @{ }

```
@{
    var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
}
```

You should really move to a Sitecore controller rendering and do this work in the controller and return the Item as your model.

```
public class YourController : Controller
    { 
        public ActionResult Stuff()
        {
            var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");

            return View(item);
        }
    }
```

Your view

```
@model Sitecore.Data.Items.Item

<div>
    @Model.DisplayName
</div>
```

Comment: Why you do't recommend using Sitecord.context.item in WebRendering?

Comment: You should never have business logic in your view. Its bad practice and untestable.

Comment: @ChrisAuer 1 line to look up a Model object to use for the HTML rendering doesn't seem like business logic to me. All View Renderings essentially do this - you have a Model object from your Data Source, and you use that Model object in the HTML. This is just 1 more lookup to another Sitecore item.

Comment: @DonCheadle I would agree if it wasn't data. Data for a view should come from the model. If you want to use functions in a view to transform something, ok. But once you get the item, where does it end? Get an item, convert a field to a link field and find the target item? It's a slippery slope. I think data comes from the model.